# Create nested list structure from a string

Tags: r, string, list

I have a string that is a composite of n substrings. It could look like this:

```
string <- c("A_AA", "A_BB", "A_BB_AAA", "B_AA", "B_BB", "B_CC")
```

Every subcomponent in this string is separated from any other by "_". Here, the first level consists of the values "A" and "B", the second level of "AA", "BB" and "CC", the third level of "AAA". Deeper nestings are possible and the solution should extend to those cases. The nestings are not necessarily balanced, e.g. "A" only has two children, while "B" has three, but it also has a grandchild which "B" has not.

Essentially, I want to recreate the nested structure in this string in some kind of R object, preferably a list. Thus, the nested list structure that would look like this:

```
list("A" = list("AA", "BB" = list("AAA")),
"B" = list("AA", "BB", "CC"))

> $A
  $A[[1]]

  [1] "AA"
  $A$BB
  $A$BB[[1]]
  [1] "CCC"

  $B
  $B[[1]]
  [1] "AA"

  $B[[2]]
  [1] "BB"

  $B[[3]]
  [1] "CC"
```

Any help on this is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it into a matrix without too much fuss...

```
string <- c("A_AA", "A_BB", "A_BB_AAA", "B_AA", "B_BB", "B_CC")

splitted<-strsplit(string,"_")
cols<-max(lengths(splitted))
mat<-do.call(rbind,lapply(splitted, "length<-", cols))
```

Comment: You could replace `lapply(x, length)` with `lengths(x)` and, also, use `do.call(rbind, lapply(splitted, "length<-", cols))` after "cols".

Comment: That results in a very different structure from the one OP wants. Unless there’s a trivial transformation from the matrix into OP’s format, I don’t think that’s what they’re after (and I don’t see that).

Comment: @KonradRudolph the OP *did* give a preference for list of lists but seemed flexible to other structures.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I don't think the matrix format will be very useful to me. I will need to use the resulting object to identify how many children/grandchildren there are under the A "node". I am not sure if this is easily posssible with a matrix (sorry for not being clear from the beginning on this).

Comment: @user3393472 It's actually much easier with matrix than list of lists.  When you do `length` on a list it treats elements that are also lists as 1, it doesn't count all the sub elements in the list.  Whereas with a matrix you can do `subset(mat,mat[,1]=="A")` and then count how many of whatever generational column are na.

Comment: @dean-macgregor, I implemented your solution and it works well enough for me. The key point for me was always to be able to query the data structure with questions about how many children/grandchildren there are under a specific node. With subset and some iteration mechanism (lapply) over the columns I can achieve exactly that. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not so straight forward, also not the most beautiful code, but it should do its job and return a list:

```
string <- c("A_AA", "A_BB", "A_BB_AAA", "B_AA", "B_BB", "B_CC")

# loop through each element of the string "str_el"
list_els <- lapply(string, function(str_el) {

  # split the string into parts
  els <- strsplit(str_el, "_")[[1]]

  # loop backwards through the elements
  for (i in length(els):1){

    # the last element gives the value
    if (i == length(els)){

      # assign the value to a list and rename the list          
      res <- list(els[[i]])
      names(res) <- els[[i - 1]]

    } else {
      # if its not the last element (value) assign the list res to another list
      # with the name of that element
      if (i != 1) {
        res <- list(res)
        names(res) <- els[[i - 1]]
      }
    }
  }

  return(res)
})

# combine the lists into one list
res_list <- mapply(c, list_els, SIMPLIFY = F)

res_list
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$A
# [1] "AA"
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$A
# [1] "BB"
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]]$A
# [[3]]$A$BB
# [1] "AAA"
# 
# 
# 
# [[4]]
# [[4]]$B
# [1] "AA"
# 
# 
# [[5]]
# [[5]]$B
# [1] "BB"
# 
# 
# [[6]]
# [[6]]$B
# [1] "CC"
```

Does that give you what you want?

Comment: Thank you, it get pretty close. For my problem it will be necessary that list_els[[1]] gives me the entire A "node" with all its children and grandchildren

Comment: It seems to be a real pain in the ****. Can you elaborate a bit more what you are trying to achieve. I would stick to @Dean's answer by using some kinds of non-list structure. Lists are really usefull in some cases, but nesting lists is not so funny.

Comment: I am sticking with Dean's solution for the moment. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way to do it. It's weird, but seems to work

```
my_relist <- function(x){
y=list()
#This first loop creates the skeleton of the list
for (name in x){
    split=strsplit(name,'_',fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
    char='y'
    l=length(split)
    for (i in 1:(l-1)){
        char=paste(char,'$',split[i],sep="")
    }
char2=paste(char,'= list()',sep="")
#Example of char2: "y$A$BB=list()"
eval(parse(text=char2))
#Evaluates the expression inside char2
}

#The second loop fills the list with the last element
for (name in x){
   split=strsplit(name,'_',fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
   char='y'
   l=length(split)
   for (i in 1:(l-1)){
       char=paste(char,'$',split[i],sep="")
   }
char3=paste(char,'=c(',char,',split[l])')
#Example of char3: "y$A = c(y$A,"BB")"
eval(parse(text=char3))
}
return(y)
}
```

And this is the result:

```
example <- c("A_AA_AAA", "A_BB", "A_BB_AAA", "B_AA", "B_BB", "B_CC")
my_relist(example)
#$A
#$BB
#1.'AAA'
#[[2]]
#'AA'
#[[3]]
#'BB'
#$B
#1.'AA'
#2.'BB'
#3.'CC'
```